# How do I pull data out of regex::Match in rust

Tags: rust

Is there a way to get the data out of a `regex::Match`? Here is my code:

```rust
for line in line_array {
    let mat = re.find(line);

    if !mat.is_none() {
        println!("{:?}", mat.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Right now it prints:

```rust
Match { text: "SomeDateHere", start: 5, end: 19 }
```

How do I get the data from here?

Comment: [Using `.as_str()`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/struct.Match.html#method.as_str)

Comment: So @Aplet123 `.as_str()` returns only the matched text in the line. I want to return the entire line from the Match. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text out of a `regex::Match` by calling [`as_str`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/struct.Match.html#method.as_str):

```rust
if let Some(mat) = re.find(line) {
   println!("{}", mat.as_str())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can extract the matched string:

In this function i am trying to get the word "up" from "up 5" using the regex pattern `[a-zA-Z]+`

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    // Create your regex
    let re: Regex = Regex::new("[a-zA-Z]+").unwrap();
    
    // Print your match
    println!("{}", re.find("up 5").unwrap().as_str());
}
```

This will print "up"

Answer (score -1):

So, thank you @Aplet123 and @Ibraheem Ahmed, basically what I really wanted was the line that there was a match. `.as_str()` returns the matched text which is not really what I wanted.

I got it working :)

let args: Vec = env::args().collect();
let re = Regex::new(r"(BODY\sContent[:])").unwrap();

```
let filename = parse_config(&args);

let log_string = read_log_file(filename);

let line_array = parse_to_array(&log_string);

for line in line_array {
    if let Some(_) = re.find(line) {
        println!("matched line: {}", line);
    }
}
```